# CSS/JS Resize figure to fit image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, figure

I experimented a littlebit with transitions and wanted to show a caption for an image on :hover. This is what I got right now:
(I tried to resize the figure itself with the sizes of the image)

```js
//Resize figure to image size
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("figure>img").load(function() {
    $(this).parent().width($(this).width());
  });
});
```

```css
figure {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  /* unvisible to fade in later */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  /* unvisible to fade in later */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  /* visible */
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  /* visible */
}
.img-middle {
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <img class="img-middle" src="img/test.png" alt="" width="700" height="500"></img>
  <figcaption>This is a cool caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

The figure never was resized.
 The problem right now is that the figure somehow has a width of 100% and therefor the `:hover` effect also triggers somewhere next to the image. I don't want to set the size of the figure manually. And when I tried `figure>img:hover figcaption { /* do stuff */ }`(to trigger the caption fade in only on image hover) it somehow didn't worked anymore.
So because that dont worked for me, I tried to resize the parent according to its childrens size...

[image: The figure is bigger then my image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you were going for?

```css
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  /* unvisible to fade in later */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* unvisible to fade in later */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
figure {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  /**
  * only an example
  */
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
figure img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%%;
  height: 100%;
}
figure > .image-container {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
figure > .image-container:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
figure > .image-container:hover figcaption {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="img-middle" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="" width="100%" />
    <figcaption>This is a cool caption</figcaption>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Isn't the figure size fixed at your solution?

Comment: oh you wanted it to change, thought only the caption

Comment: on what event does it change?

Comment: something like this?

Comment: I uploaded an image. There you can see that my `figure` is bigger then my image. So wenn I hover over the blank white space, the `:hover` effect also triggers. I just want to trigger the :hover on image hover

Comment: you can see it in the figure:hover, does this work as you intended now?

Comment: Is it possible to have `figure > img:hover` so that it's on image with parent figure :hover and not on figure hover ?

Comment: anything can be accomplished XD i just need to know the behavior you want to achieve, because right now this is my understanding of your question

Comment: i updated my answer i hope this helps, this time i only increase the size of the image, that expands the figure, this then expands the size of the caption since its position is relative to the figure

Comment: Okay I will try to express myself in a better way.
I want to archieve:
- A hover effect when I hover over the image, the real visible image! In my picture you can see that the image width is smaller then the figure with. I don't want to set a size property for the `figure`. The current problem is, that when I hover over the blank space at the right the caption also is shown. You solution is just 50% correct for me. I dont want to have fixed size properties for the image or figure.
Image size > make figure fit to image size > hover when curser is over figure **which has image size**. Thx :)

Comment: ok i updated the code, i added the border to show the size of the figure, to see the blank spaces, notice that when you hover them the image doesnt change

Comment: Okay, the solution with the `div.image-container` worked! :D
Thanks a lot, totally forgot to try that out.

Comment: finally XD, please close this question so we can both move on with our lives :P